# Data preparation for Discrete Choice Experiment

Tags: dplyr

I am a newbie in R programming and Discrete choice experiments.
I have synthetic data set which I need to prepare for the analysis. My current data format is this
[Current data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxL75.png)

I want my data to be in this format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8guVs.png)

I know dplyr is a useful tool in this case, but i am puzzled how to do the coding...
Can any altruist help me?

I am stuck with the process.

Comment: Hi Tahsin! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you be able to run dput on your data, and then copy paste the results into your question? Thanks!

Comment: if the data is too large, you can get the first 50 or so rows, and run dput on those instead

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.